# Xliff - How to read attributes with Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi, xliff

I'm working on an import function for certain fields in an XML-based document.

The Reading of the values ​​ansich works perfectly, unfortunately, I can do it does not really attributes of the trans-unit namely read the id.

My code:

```
procedure TForm2.importXliff;
var
  i: Integer;
  TransUnits: IXMLNodeList;
  ID: IXMLNodeList;
begin
  if OpenDialog.Execute then
  begin
    //XMLDocument erzeugen und xml-Datei laden
    xmlDoc := newXMLDocument;
    xmlDoc.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
    Memo1.Lines := xmlDoc.XML;
    xmlDoc.Active := True;
    TransUnits := xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['file'].ChildNodes['body'].ChildNodes;
    ID := xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['body'].ChildNodes;

      for i := 0 to TransUnits.Count-1 do
        ListBox.Items.Add(TransUnits[i].ChildNodes['source'].Text);
        //xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['trans-unit'].AttributeNodes['id'].Text
  end;
 end;
```

My xml based text document (Xliff file):

```
<xliff version="1.1">
  <file original="myfile.ext" datatype="plaintext" Source-language="en-US" target-language="fr-FR">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id='#1'>
        <source>Der Text.</source>
        <target>Le texte.</target>
      </trans-unit>

      <trans-unit id='#2'>
        <source>Das Flugzeug</source>
        <target>l'avion.</target>
      </trans-unit>

      <trans-unit id='#3'>
        <source>Der Baum.</source>
      </trans-unit>

   </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

My question now is how I can read the trans-unit ID?

Comment: Sidenote, you don't have to create new document by using `NewXMLDocument` with subsequent activation; it's enough to use `LoadXMLDocument` function for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`IXMLNodeList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNodeList) is a collection of [`IXMLNode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode) items in whose you can access attributes by name through the [`Attributes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.Attributes) property. In pseudo code it might look like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  TransUnits: IXMLNodeList;
  XMLDocument: IXMLDocument;
begin
  XMLDocument := LoadXMLDocument('d:\File.xml');
  if Assigned(XMLDocument) then
  begin
    TransUnits := XMLDocument.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['file'].ChildNodes['body'].ChildNodes;
    for I := 0 to TransUnits.Count - 1 do
      ShowMessage(TransUnits[I].Attributes['id']);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for this answer. Im new with xml and parsing.